# How to implement new user email verification in MVC with forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I am using forms authentication and MVC 3 and would like to confirm registration via email.  How would I implement this in the most simplest way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the custom membership provider sample for mvc here that provides this functionality.
http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/12/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-3/